# What differences are between a hash file organization and a hash index organization?

Tags: database, data-structures, hash, rdbms, database-indexes

From Database System Concepts

> Hashing can be used for two different purposes.
>
> - In a hash file organization, we obtain the address of the disk block containing a desired record directly by computing a function on the
>     search-key value of the record.
> - In a hash index organization we organize the search keys, with their associated pointers, into **a hash file structure**.

What does "a hash file structure" means?

I am not sure about it, so I am not sure what differences are between a hash ﬁle organization and a hash index organization.
Could you show or rephrase what they are respectively?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Imagine that you have two records, one with the key "foo" and one with the key "bar". Let's just say that the records are fixed length of 64 bytes, and that "foo" hashes to 0x4000 and "bar" hashes to 0x0100.

In a "hash file organization", you have a function that takes the search key and computes an address directly. So if you add "foo" and "bar" to the file, the record for "foo" will start at address 0x4000 in the file, and the "bar" record will start at address 0x0100 in the file.

The file would look something like this:

```
Address Range         Contents
-------------         --------
0x0000 - 0x00FF       empty space
0x0100 - 0x013F       "bar" record
0x0140 - 0x3FFF       empty space
0x0400 - 0x403F       "foo" record
```

In a "hash index organization", you have a secondary data structure--an index--that tells you where a particular record starts. Say the file is empty and you add "foo". Your hash function computes a value of 0x4000. You add that to the index (a hash map or something similar), and since the file is empty the value assigned is 0. When you add the second record, "bar", the hash key of 0x0100 is added, and the value assigned is 0x0040. You have an index:

```
Key     Value
-------------
0x0100  0x0040
0x4000  0x0000
```

And the file looks like this:

```
Address Range        Contents
-----------------------------
0x0000 - 0x003F      "foo" record
0x0040 - 0x007F      "bar" record
```

And of course you have to store the index somewhere. That can be in a separate file, or perhaps at the front or back of the data file, or scattered throughout. Lots of different possibilities.

In the first case, there's a lot of wasted space in the file, but you can look up a record's position directly: hash the key and the result is the record's address.

In the second case, you hash the key, and then look up the result in the index to obtain the record's key. The primary advantage here is that it potentially saves a whole lot of space in the file, but you have the trouble of where to store the index.

In either case, you must have some way of resolving hash collisions.

Comment: Thanks. Also appreciate if you could consider https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50909435/is-a-hash-index-never-a-clustering-index